# Lua - Take Multiple inputs

Tags: lua

I want to write a program that calculate the **Average of all input numbers**.

First it will asks "How many number you want to input"
If users type 5 then the program will take 5 inputs Then it calculates the Average of it.

I wrote a function that takes passed numbers & returns average of of it But How do we ask the user to input multiple inputs and save it in array

Comment: Please add the code you have written.

Comment: where does that user input come from? command line? a file?  did you read the Lua manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lua
local num = nil;

local sum = 0;

local n = 0;

while num != 0 do
    num = io.read()
    sum = sum + tonumber(num)
    n = n + 1;
end

print(sum / (n-1))
```

this code will calculate all inputs and will stop asking for input until the user types `0`, when he types 0, he will print the average of the values entered